# What is UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey used for?

Tags: ios, push-notification

if I understand correctly, the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` key is used on the `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` method when 
- the push was received when the application was **not running** (e.g. killed)
- the user clicked on the received push

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSDictionary *userInfo = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if(userInfo) {
        // app was not running and the user clicked on the push
    }
}
```

but .. in this exact same case, the `-[AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:]` is also called just after the previous one.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
{
    // called when
    // app was not running and the user clicked on the push
    // app was running in background and user clicked on a push
    // app was running in background and a silent push was received
    // app is in foreground and a push is received
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

So the question is, why should I use the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` if everything can be handled in the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` delegate? Did I miss something?

cheers,

Jan

Comment: because you should be able to handle remote notifications somewhere deeply in the navigation stack in a random _view_... or a just in a random _controller_... or just in a random _model_... it is illogical to rely on the app-delegate would do the changes on your e.g. _model_, that would make no sense to do so, that is why individual instances can listen to notifications and if they are awake they can make the changes immediately, independently from app-delegate – technically in the last three scenarios, you have mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

In case when the app is killed and user taps on push notification in notification center, `launchingOptions` dictionary contains `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` so that you can adjust your app start logic.
In prior iOS version there wasn't `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:` and `launchingOptions` dictionary from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` was the only place where you could handle remote notification on app start.

My guess is that `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` contains UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey for compatibility reasons.

Comment: I see, so if I do implement the newer `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:` I should be covered, correct ?

Comment: Documentation doesn't state that this method calls when application is started from scratch (i.e. when the app is killed) but if your tests confirms that it gets called then you should be covered.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of this key indicates that a remote notification is available for the app to process. The value of this key is an NSDictionary containing the payload of the remote notification.